# immutable.js: remove an item in a set

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

So I have an immutable.js Set of event objects.

The Set is an attribute on a `Calendar` object:

```
const Calendar = new Record({
    'events': new Set(), // set of Events
});
```

I'm using Redux, and firing off actions to add and to remove events from a `Calendar`:

adding Events to a Calendar works fine if you pass it in the appropriate objects and construct the object from those in my reducer:

```
case ADD_EVENT_TO_CURRENT_CALENDAR:
    return state.updateIn(['events'], (events)=> events.add({
        start: action.event.date,
        end: action.event.date,
        title: `${action.event.show.venue}`,
        show: action.event.show,
        boundActions: action.boundActions,
    }));
```

one of the `boundActions` on an event is a `removeEventFromCurrentCalendar` action. Calling that on the current event triggers the following in the reducer:

```
case REMOVE_EVENT_FROM_CURRENT_CALENDAR:
    return state.updateIn(['events'], (events)=> {
        events.delete(action.event);
    });
```

`action.event` is equivalent to the current event in the form specified in `ADD_EVENT...`, i.e.:

```
    {
        start,
        end,
        title,
        show,
        boundActions,
    }
```

However, it is not the *exact* same object, which is what I am guessing is tripping up the `.delete()` call.

What is the best way to remove this similar, but not same, object from this set using immutable.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to manually exclude the object.

```
arr.filter((item) => {
    return item.start !== toDelete.start &&
        item.end !== toDelete.start && ...etc
})
```

FWIW, it'd be easier to filter if each item in the array kept a unique ID. Then you only need to compare a single value rather than the object structure.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that you change `Record` to `Map` and the `Set` to `List`, then when updating the events `List` with a new event you can store a index reference within it (these should also be `Map` although a `Record` is probably fine too).

It becomes pretty trivial to then remove it later using `Immutable.List.delete`.